# How can I make a tuple out of a list?

Tags: python, list, input, integer, tuples

```
month = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']  

converting_list = month 

print(converting_list)  

print(type(converting_list))
```

a tuple out of a list

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `mytuple = tuple(month)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tuple()` function

```
month = 
['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']

converting_list = tuple(month)

print(type(converting_list))
```

This returns...

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
print(tuple(month))
```

try this basic to change list directly to tuple without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **tuple** method:

```
list_to_tuple = tuple(month)
```